# Why did a party with more votes get fewer seats in the 2019 European Parliament election in Denmark?

Tags: voting-systems, european-parliament, denmark

The [official result](http://dst.dk/valg/Valg1684426/valgopg/valgopgHL.htm) of the [2019 European Parliament election in Denmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_European_Parliament_election_in_Denmark) is:

```
Parti                                 Antal   Pct.  Mandater

A. Socialdemokratiet                592.645  21,5%   3
B. Radikale Venstre                 277.929  10,1%   2
C. Det Konservative Folkeparti      170.544   6,2%   1
F. SF - Socialistisk Folkeparti     364.895  13,2%   2
I. Liberal Alliance                  60.693   2,2%   -
N. Folkebevægelsen mod EU           102.101   3,7%   -
O. Dansk Folkeparti                 296.978  10,8%   1
V. Venstre, Danmarks Liberale Parti 648.203  23,5%   4
Ø. Enhedslisten - De Rød-Grønne     151.903   5,5%   1
Å. Alternativet                      92.964   3,4%   -

I alt gyldige stemmer             2.758.855
...
```

Party "B" (Radikale Venstre) got 10.1%, resulting in 2 seats.
Party "O" (Dansk Folkeparti) got 10.8%, resulting in 1 seat.

How is this possible? Wikipedia says that [the D'Hondt method is used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_Denmark#European_elections), but I understand the [D'Hondt method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Hondt_method) to be consistent and monotonic, meaning that a party could only get more seats than another party by getting more votes.  Is Denmark actually using some other method? Are there extra rules about coalitions or something, that aren't reflected in the results? Or is there some mistake in the numbers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I've correctly understood this [auto-translated Danish article](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jv.dk%2Findland%2FManglende-valgforbund-sender-mandat-fra-DF-til-De-Radikale%2Fartikel%2F2720698), Radikale Venstre (Social Liberals) were in an election alliance with Alternativet (The Alternative), so the votes of the latter were added to the former, granting it an extra seat.

Comment: Or the [Danish Wikipedia article](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa-Parlamentsvalget_2019_i_Danmark)

Comment: So if I understand correctly now, the votes only get added when an allied party misses the threshold to get its own seat.

Comment: @krubo Or what my guess would be: The Radikale Venstre plus Alternativet alliance is entitled to  2 seats with their 13.5%. These two seats were then distributet *within* the alliance (again by d'Hondt), but as 10.1% is so much more than 3.4%, both seats went to the Radical Left

Comment: Steve Melnikoff is right